# Creating a program that accumulates parts of a list - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, helper

I'm working on a program the will takes a list of triples and depending on one of those being true, I want to find the sum of one of the other parts of the triple.

```
totalWeightOfFirstClass :: [Parcel] -> Weight
totalWeightOfFirstClass [] = go
totalWeightOfFirstClass ((weight, postcode, firstclass):xs) =
  if firstclass == True then
    go weight
    totalWeightOfFirstClass xs
  else
    totalWeightOfFirstClass xs
where
  go :: Int -> Int
  go _ = 0
  go x =
```

So the program should add up all the weight values in the list and display it at the end only if the that triple was first class. So far I have a helper statement that I want to accumulate all the values and to eventually display at the end.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Regards, Kieran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the sum of the weights where the parcel is sent first class, this should do the trick:

```
totalWeightOfFirstClass :: [Parcel] -> Weight
totalWeightOfFirstClass [] = 0
totalWeightOfFirstClass ((weight, postcode, firstclass):xs)
    | firstclass = weight + totalWeightOfFirstClass xs
    | otherwise = totalWeightOfFirstClass xs
```

Comment: That's going to be rather inefficient. Can you see why?

Comment: @dfeuer I suppose if you filtered first it would get rid of the extra memory being carried around and be a tad quicker, but it's tail recursive and just seems to be a standard recursive implementation of a sum function, am I missing something? I would personally implement it in a similar way to HuStmpHrrr's solution but I wanted to keep it a bit easier to understand.

Comment: @dfeuer I can't see why. Perhaps you could say yourself?

Comment: @DanielWagner, despite Zpalmtree's claim in the comment above, it's *not* tail recursive.

Comment: @dfeuer Isn't tail recursion where the last statement is the function you're recursing on, so the stack frame is done with and can be reused?

Comment: Indeed. Look at the `firstclass = True` case.

Comment: @dfeuer Ah, my bad, I got confused on how it worked. I guess you would have to use an extra parameter to store the sum if you wanted it to be tail recursive. I just tested it out and even with -O3 it doesn't get optimized. I guess I should avoid recursion like this then, I often use it instead of foldr because I find it easier to read but I didn't realise it wasn't optimized

Comment: `foldr` won't (directly) help you here. You can use `foldl'`, which is easy, or you can use `foldr` in a tricky higher-order way, in which the fold produces a *function* you apply to the result (`0` here) in the base case. Something like `foldr go id xs 0 where go x r !acc = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

That's too much work in your code. Try to consider using general combinator to express your code, instead of writing primitive recursion like this.

```
totalWeightOfFirstClass = sum . (fmap (\(weight, _, _) -> weight)) . filter (\(_, _, firstc) -> firstc)
```

It sum all the weights after applying the filter. As you can see, the code is very clean to read.

Comment: You can break up the long chain using `let` or `where` to make this easier to read. At the very least, add some line breaks and comments!

Comment: Just a few helper functions make a huge readability difference. After defining `weight (w,_,_) = w; firstclass (_,_,fc) = fc`, this becomes `sum . map weight . filter firstclass`.

Comment: @DanielWagner definitely. if it's a `data` type and is defined in a record syntax, those functions are free.